# How to use a variable value declared in servlet into a new Java class?

Tags: java

I have a login servlet where I have a login query in my post method from the query I am getting **username**, **password**, **company name** and  **ID**

I am storing all this values in a variable like

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String companyDB,nameDB,idDB;

        try {
                    con = DBConnection.createConnection();
                    statement = con.createStatement();
                    String sql = "  SELECT MT_USERS.MT_USERS_VCLOGINCODE AS USERID, MT_USERS.MT_USERS_VCUSERPASSWORD AS PASSWORDID, MT_USERS.MT_USERS_VCUSERNAME AS NAME, (SELECT MT_DISTRIBUTR_VCDISTRIBUTRNAME FROM MT_DISTRIBUTR WHERE MT_DISTRIBUTR_VCDISTRIBUTRCODE = MT_USERS.MT_DISTRIBUTR_VCDISTRIBUTRCODE) AS COMPANYNAME ,(SELECT mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode FROM mt_distributr WHERE MT_DISTRIBUTR_VCDISTRIBUTRCODE = MT_USERS.MT_DISTRIBUTR_VCDISTRIBUTRCODE) AS ID FROM MT_USERS WHERE MT_USERS_VCLOGINCODE='admin' AND MT_USERS_VCUSERPASSWORD ='admin'";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (resultSet.next()) {

                        companyDB = resultSet.getString("COMPANYNAME");
                        nameDB = resultSet.getString("name");
                        idDB = resultset.getString("ID");  


                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

}
}
```

Now I have an another class where I am writing a query and in that query I want to use **idDB** like

My new class is

```
 public class Outlet {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public List<String> getoutlet() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();

        try {

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ecustomer where CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER in(select CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER from mt_distributrol where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = 'AAAA'");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                list.add(resultSet.getString("CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

Where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = 'AAAA'" at the place of 'AAAA' I have to pass a variable which has the value of **idDB**

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatment` and use the `setString` method

Comment: @ScaryWombat  setString(1,"AAAA") that AAAA is comming from my loging query if someone else is loging in it may be "AAAB" so i cannot put it by my own.please give me any suggestion

Comment: you need to get the values from the `request.getParameter` method as per normal web form processing

Answer (score 2):

You may use a prepared statement here:

```
String sql = "SELECT CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR FROM ecustomer WHERE CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER IN (";
sql += "SELECT CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER FROM mt_distributrol ";
sql += "WHERE mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = ?)");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "AAAA");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    list.add(resultSet.getString("CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR"));
}
```

I actually find that MkYong does a good job of explaining prepared statements in Java, [see here](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/), but any good documentation is a good place to start looking. And see [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: that 'AAAA' is comming from db only i cannot define it statically

Comment: @hey you there?

Comment: setString(1,"AAAA")  that AAAA is comming from my loging query if someone else is loging in  it may be "AAAB" so i cannot put it by my own.please give me any suggestion

Comment: The statement I gave you above is generic, and accept _any_ bound string parameter.  So, if you have a value, then you may bind it.  If you don't know the value to be used in the query, then how can you possibly proceed?

Comment: i said that i have a logging in query from where i am getting the value which is idDB="AAAA", it can be different from for diff - diff users, so from one query i am getting the values now i want to use that value in other query which is in different java class

Comment: I don't understand your question then.

Comment: i am totally confused now :(

Comment: come to the chat box i ll explain you there please

Comment: looks like he doesn't know how to get the HTTP posted value

Comment: @ScaryWombat i knew that i am getting username and password from input feild from my html form ,but there is no input feild for idDB

Comment: Oh, then you will need to change your HTML form (jsp or whatever) to provide one unless it is stored in the `Session`

Comment: @ScaryWombat no on my ui i can only provide 2 input feild i.e userid and password but to check that userid and password i am  writing a querry which is giving me userid password and ID i.e "AAAA" and that ID i want to use in another query which is in another class(java)